# Excel VBA save window keeps popping up

Tags: excel, vba

So for this code I copied  it to my current workbook/module from another workbook. However, whenever I run it, I get a popup window saying  Update Values: otherfileipastedthecodefrom.xlsx. This popup comes right after the ssReport.Paste line. Any idea about why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
im summaryView
Dim ssReport
Dim detailedData
Sub insertStyles()

Set summaryView = Worksheets("Summary View")
Set ssReport = Worksheets("Style-store report")
Set detailedData = Worksheets("Detailed Style-Store Level Data")
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim i
i = 4

' #1 loop through styles in first sheet, copy format, then loop again and copy style name/code
lastRow = summaryView.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
currentColumn = 2

' Loop to copy and paste format for all required styles
Do While i < lastRow

    ssReport.Select
    Range(Columns(currentColumn), Columns(currentColumn + 1)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ssReport.Range(Columns(currentColumn + 3), Columns(currentColumn + 4)).Select
    ssReport.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    currentColumn = currentColumn + 3
    i = i + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you also copy some formulas? Do those formulas contain remote workbook references to otherfileipastedthecodefrom.xlsx? Is there a linked table?

Comment: I have a reference to table 13, but its named the same in each file. What's a linked table?

Comment: [Excel linked table](https://www.bing.com/search?q=excel+linked+table)

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = false
```

Not solve this problem?